# Looping mysql queries in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am scraping tables on several webpages and updating a MYSQL database with items in the tables.  I am using the MYSQL module and am running into all sorts of errors when looping through all the rows.  Here is one iteration of function:

```
  var connection = mysql.createConnection(opts);
  connection.connect();

function updateDB(o,lang){
  var tbl_name = "news_"+lang;
  o.forEach(function(entry,index,arr){
      var sql1 = "SELECT * FROM "+tbl_name+" WHERE url = '"+htmlencode.htmlEncode(entry.url)+"' and omit = '1'";
      connection.query(sql1, function(err, rows, fields) {
        connection.end();
        if (err){
          console.log("can't run query=" + sql1 +"\n Error="+err);
        }
        else{
          console.log('ROWS:',rows);
          // if rows.length = 0 then update table with new info here...
        }
      });
  }); 
};
```

This actually works if I comment out the connection.end() line but then the connection never ends and the process stays alive forever.  I am running this as a batch script so I need it to end gracefully.  With the connection.end() in place I am getting a `"Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit."`

I tried putting the `connection.end` in a final callback using async.series but that still does not work.  I've tried using pools and different iterations of code to try to get something to work.  I'm at my wits end with using the mysql module and wondering if there is another one that would work better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only have one connection and you're using `.forEach` which is not asynchronous friendly.

You should use a pool of connections and `async.eachLimit` to control concurrency.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_NAME,
  connectionLimit: 10
});

function updateDB(o,lang){
  // submit as a sub-function to get the `lang` closure
  // this could probably be organized a different way, but this fits your structure
  function submit(entry, callback) {
    var tbl_name = "news_"+lang;
    var sql = [
      'SELECT * FROM ' + tbl_name,
      ' WHERE url="?" and omit="1"'
    ].join('');
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if(err) return callback(err);
      connection.query(sql, [entry.url], function(err, results) {
        connection.release();
        if(err) return callback(err);
        console.log('ROWS:',results);
      });
    });
  }

  async.eachLimit(o, 10, submit, function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Done processing');
  });
}
```

You should almost always use a pool, even if you don't need more than one connection.  A pool will recreate connections as needed.  This is very handy as your connection can die from mysql timeouts, network issues and any number of other reasons.  When you use a pool, your code will be more robust.

If you only want to do one query at a time, just change the second parameter to `async.eachLimit` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks but I am having the same issue where connection never ends so I never get the "Done processing" console log.